# Is it possible to export animations from Blender to Unity prefab without re-exporting entire character?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, character

I have a fully rigged and animated character that I recently exported from Blender as an FBX to Unity. I need to make more animations for the character now but I am very tired of exporting the entire character every time I make a change. I do not need to update texture coordinates or vertex weights (probably). Is there a way to record a new animation in Blender and attach it to the existing Unity character?

Or alternatively, is there now a viable way to produce quality animations for characters inside of Unity? My character needs to move fingers and toes but does not have facial animations.